# How to convert from string to date data type?

Tags: mongodb, date, csv, type-conversion

[image]

I am uploading data from a csv file to MongoDB. It is taking `OrderDate` as string data type due to which facing problems while creating reports using a BI tool.
I have about 10000 records in my collection.

Could anyone help me how can I change the data Type of `OrderDate` to Date with a single query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think that you can change field's type with single query. The easiest way is to convert data strings into `Date` format using `ISODate` function during the insertion. But, if  you want to process the data you already inserted, you can do it with the following code using mongodb console:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(element){
  element.OrderDate = ISODate(element.OrderDate);
  db.collection.save(element);
})
```

This code will process each element in your collection `collection` and change the type of `Orderdate` field from `String` to `Date`.

Comment: ThankYou that was really helpfull. But here  I see its creating a new feild. Is there anyway to change the existing one without creating a new field.

Comment: It's rewriting the old field with the new value, not creating the new one.

Comment: @divya MongoDB is case-sensitive. You took the value from `OrderDate` field and placed the new one into **another** field `Orderdate`, instead of using the same one. I edited both you question and my answer  with the correct field name.

Comment: How do I convert it the opposite way from a date type to a string... having a hard time.

Comment: @Lion789 have you tried [.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)?

Comment: As an FYI to others, `Collection.save()` is deprecated. The error notes: "Use insertOne, insertMany, updateOne or updateMany."

Answer (score 1):

```
db.messages.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.headers.datestamp = new Date(Date.parse(doc.headers.Date.toString())); 
  db.messages.save(doc);
  })
```

This worked well to convert this sort of text:
  Tue, 14 Nov 2007 03:22:00 -0800 (PST)

The text is from an email archive known as the Enron Corpus.

Comment: As an FYI to others, `Collection.save()` is deprecated. The error notes: "Use insertOne, insertMany, updateOne or updateMany."