# Select and order all subdocuments from a collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have the following documents in a collection:

```
{
  "thread_object": "Sed consectetur, massa id aliquam lacinia",
  "thread_comments": [
    {
      "comment_date": "11/01/2014 17:23:19",
      "comment_user": "Integer",
      "comment_content": "In suscipit enim at eleifend auctor"
    },
    {
      "comment_date": "12/01/2014 17:23:19",
      "comment_user": "Suspendisse",
      "comment_content": "Quisque facilisis magna pellentesque diam mollis"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "thread_object": "Vivamus auctor mauris augue",
  "thread_comments": []
},
{
  "thread_object": "Phasellus volutpat, sem id convallis elementum",
  "thread_comments": [
    {
      "comment_date": "10/01/2014 17:23:19",
      "comment_user": "Donec",
      "comment_content": "Suspendisse a pellentesque justo"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I retrieve an ordered list of all the comments?

```
{
  "comment_date": "10/01/2014 17:23:19",
  "comment_user": "Donec",
  "comment_content": "Suspendisse a pellentesque justo"
},
{
  "comment_date": "11/01/2014 17:23:19",
  "comment_user": "Integer",
  "comment_content": "In suscipit enim at eleifend auctor"
},
{
  "comment_date": "12/01/2014 17:23:19",
  "comment_user": "Suspendisse",
  "comment_content": "Quisque facilisis magna pellentesque diam mollis"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `thread_comments` array and then sort by `comment_date`.  However, **since the date is stored as String**, if you sort by `comment_date`, the **results will NOT be sorted**.  You might want to convert the comment_date to Date() using javascript.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473772/how-to-convert-from-string-to-date-data-type).  There are other similar questions on SO too.

Assuming you have converted comment_date to Date(), a query like below will work:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$thread_comments"},
    {$sort:{"thread_comments.comment_date":-1}}
])
```