# Filter and re-arrange results using node.js and mongodb according to date(month)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a server using Node.JS and Express. Database is MongoDB and ORM is Mongoose. Here's what I have to do.

```
    {
        "_id": "5788fcf7bfecf0c135178418",
        "incomeDate": "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "name": "Sales",
        "type": "Sales one",
        "amount": 5500,
        "__v": 0
    }
```

This is the object I'm getting from database. I want to filter these objects by date ( actually by month). I'm going to display monthly income in a chart using Angular Charts. (https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) -> Angular Bar chart.

So if there's no amount in a specific month, there shoud be zero (0) in the list. The list must be like this. there are 12 elements of the list. This is just an example.

> [200,1200,10,0,124,542,1254,500,0,1254,36,87]

How can I do this in node.js and mongoose ? Have to filter using incomedate and do some code in node.js.....

Comment: You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to filter using only months and put a check if the data you are fetching is null, put a _zero_ at its place in the array.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik Hey buddy, you have an example ? And how can we integrate momentjs with mongoose to query database ?

Comment: just do `npm install moment` and it is ready to use. I dont have example with me right now but if your go through the link i share, you will get the fair idea about how to use this library. It is very easy and can be useful for all time related issues you may face in your node app.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik Can you plz tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
var date = new incomeDate();

{$group: {date: date.getMonth()}
```

Hey run your codes and see what error you get and we work around to fix them.

Comment: How can we add zero if there's no value for a certain month ? It's not happening in this code.. Is it ?