# Time rollup data on collection using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the latest version of mongoose. My model looks like this:

`{
  id:'',
  name:'',
  text:'',
  createdAt:Date
}`

Now I'd like to create a query that is giving me a [minute] rollup.

For instance let's say I have 3 entries in my collection.
a) createdAt: 12:50
b) createdAt: 12:50
c) createdAt: 12:51

If I want to have minute rollups, I would want to have a result like this:

`{
 12:50: 2,
 12:51: 1
}`

I've tried a few different aggregations, but none of them really worked.

Comment: Try `db.col.aggregate(  [   {$group: { _id :{$minute:"$createdAt"},      count:{$sum: 1 }    }  }  ])`

Comment: Yes, look at the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366497/2683814) which does something similar for month. Also, I have noted solution applicable for your case in my previous comment.