# Use the value of a queried field in $set on Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to convert all non-date types (ISO strings, unix timestamps...) to js Date objects. So is there a way to modify the value of a field natively in Mongo? I'm thinking something along the lines of `$inc` - as it modifies the current value in place.

For example: given the following doc structure in the "projects" collection:

```
{
  _id: '123456',
  created: '1449224127049',
  name: 'My document',
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
db.projects.update(
  {created: {$not: {$type: 9} } },
  {$set: {created: new Date( ??? ) } },
  {multi: true}
);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot update a field with values referring to the same (or any other) field. You will find [questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) about this issue, and also an open [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458).

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473772/how-to-convert-from-string-to-date-data-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the [`$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) works only on arrays.

However, here is how I'd do it.

### Selecting the documents

In order to get only the records which are not already dates, we have to match the [$type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) of `created` in each document and return only the documents which do not have a date type on `created`. This can be achieved with

```js
db.projects.find({"created":{ $not:{ $type:9 }}})
```

We want the highest selectivity here, returning only documents which we really need to process, since the following steps will be rather expensive.

### Creating the dates

Next, we need to iterate over the documents returned and set the `created` field accordingly. However, we have a problem, since we can not simply pass a string of seconds since epoch to `Date()`. So you need to implement a parsing logic based on what you have. Let's have a look at an example for the problem.

In the mongo shell

```js
new Date('1449224127049')
```

returns

```js
ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")
```

The problem here is that we need to implement a parsing logic, which is not easy to achieve, since `parseInt("2015-12-04T11:27:36.806Z")` happily returns `2015`., This parsing logic can get pretty complex and a bit out of scope of this answer, however, you'd need to implement it based on your needs and data.

### Updating the documents

Updating the documents can be achieved pretty easily and with good performance using [bulk operations][mongo:bulk]. Basically, you "queue" operations. The pitfall here would be to write back the complete document, which might interfere with other write operations. So we need to explicitly use `$set` on the `created` field in order to minimize the impact of our operation.

### Putting it all together

Given you example, here is how you can achieve your goal

```js
function parseDate(value){
  // This needs to be HEAVILY expanded
  var intValue = parseInt(value);
  if( isNaN(intValue) ){
    return;
  }
  return new ISODate(intValue);
}

var bulk = db.projects.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

var docs = db.projects.find({"created":{ $not:{ $type:9 }}});
var updated = 0;
docs.forEach(
  function(doc){
    var date = parseDate(doc.created);
    if ( typeof date === "undefined" ) {
      return;
    } else {
      bulk.find({"_id":doc._id}).update({$set:{"created":date}});
      updated++;
    }
    // Batch size is 1000 anyway, and a status is nice.
    if (updated % 1000 == 0){
       print("Updated: " + updated);
       bulk.execute();
       // We can not reuse an executed bulk
       bulk = db.projects.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
  }
)
// Execute the remainder of documents
bulk.execute()
```

### Some notes

- Please, whatever you do on your data: *Make a backup before trying anything*. Modifying your data the wrong way may easily cause loss of data or precision.
- I (Markus) will post this as a [community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) so that others feel more free to edit my admittedly hacky JS – I am simply not too much of a JS wiz (quite the contrary).
- Maybe the date parsing can be achieved through a third party library.