# Convert String to Date in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

How do I convert a String like "11/21/2012" to Date in MongoDB?

I tried the following

```
obj.as_from = ISODate("11/21/2012");
```

and got this error

> uncaught exception: invalid ISO date

Is there a simple way to convert the string above?

Comment: Are you just using the mongo shell? If so, you can use the regular Date() constructor and it will return an ISODate

Comment: When I use Date("11/21/2012") I get the current date...

Comment: Use the `new` operator. See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by user602525, in the Mongo shell.

```
obj.as_from = new Date("11/21/2012");
```

Do not forget to use the `new` operator.

Comment: Ok this works, any idea how to handle a string like "11/2012"? One that only shows the month and year. When I try that it defaults to 1970.

Comment: In this case I would parse the date string manually and use the Date constructor: `new Date(2012, 10)`. Months start from zero in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks again. I notice the day deaults to "01". Is there a way to get it to default to "00" to represent nothing?

Comment: A date represents some given fixed point in time. Without a day number it just wouldn't be a date and you'd better stick with a string.

Comment: @Calimero that's what I was thinking. I actually have two dates in the document. One with a short month/year format and one that is more detailed. I just convert the detailed one and the the short format as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You try doing like that:

ISODate("11-21-2012T05:00:00.000Z")