# MongoDB [NodeJS] find only documents with array elements in range

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with a history. I want to find documents with a special history entry.
History-Element:

```
{
    name:"added",
    date: Isodate
}
```

The query should get all documents where name is "added" and the date is lower than a reference. In case of having a date that is higher, the document should be skipped. A document can have multiple "added" events

Here's my query, to find all documents with added history elements in the range of 7 days, if one element is lower than 7 days, the document should not be displayed:

```
 var expiryDate = new Date();
 expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() - 7);

 var query = {
        $and: [
            {
                history: {
                    $elemMatch:{
                        event: "added",
                        date: {
                            $not: {
                                $gte: expiryDate.toISOString()
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                history: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        event: "added",
                        date: {
                            $lt: expiryDate.toISOString()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here's the call:

```
self.db.items.find(query).toArray(function (err, items) { 
    if(items)
       console.log(items.length);
});
```

The problem is, that only the $lte part works. If there's a date greater than the reference it will be outputted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an alternative such as the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)**. Running the following pipeline would give you the desired result, with the `history` array filtered according the the given date criteria.

**Note**: There is no deed to cast the JavaScript Date object to an ISOString as Mongo wraps objects of **[`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#date)** type with the ISODate helper but internally the native JS Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into the past and future.

```
var expiryDate = new Date();
expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() - 7);

var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "history.event": "added",
            "history.date": { "$lt": expiryDate }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "other_fields": 1, 
            "history": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$history",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    {  
                                        "$and": [
                                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.event", "added" ]}
                                            { "$lt": [ "$$el.date", expiryDate ]}
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$$el",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The above pipeline involves filtering the `history` array so that you remove the documents which do not satisfy the above given criteria. This is made possible through the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operators.

The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative compliment of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final `history` array that has elements not related to the parent documents via the `date` and `event` properties.

Comment: Tyvm for this, I'm right now testing it. I'll response as soon as I get it work :)

Comment: It works. I have ISO-Strings as date in the database. Without .toISOString() I will not get any results unfortunately.

Comment: This is partly the reason why your initial query isn't working. Doing comparisons with dates/timestamps is more efficient than string values and it is recommended to either store all your dates as Date objects in UTC, or, a consistent timezone possibly related to the local datacenter, and then convert your date values to the proper local timezone on the client. Since you have have ISO-Strings as date, it is the client-side responsibility to filter and process this value as mongo treats it like a string. You can convert to date with this [**answer**.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34837902/122005)