# Change date storage format in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In an input json file i receive dates in this format:

```
{ "dt_received" : "2016-01-22T12:35:52.123+05" }
```

When loaded into MongoDB, those dates are stored this way:

```
dt_received: "2016-01-22T07:35:52.123Z"
```

The issue is that i need the timezone to calculate my indicator.
In constraint, i can't create new columns such as "dt_received_timezone".
So i'm looking for changing the date storage format into MongoDB in order to make the timezone appear (or at least not disapear)
Is it a way to to this? Or any solution ?

Comment: if you store the `dt_received` as a real `Date`, you get all of this for free. For example, enter `new ISODate('2016-01-22T07:35:52.123Z').getTimezoneOffset()` in your mongo-shell, you'll get `-60`. Is that what you need?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931) may be of help.

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for. I would like to retrieve the +05 information, in order to have my original date/hour 12:35:52.

Comment: Is there any reason for that? When you render data in Javascript as `new Date('2016-01-22T07:35:52.123Z')` it will show `2016-01-22T12:35:52.123+05`, given the browser's timezone is +5.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive data from various time zones and want to keep the time zone offset, you will have to save it into the database like this:

```
var now = new Date();
db.data.save( { date: now, offset: now.getTimezoneOffset() } );
```

You can then reconstruct the original time like this

```
var record = db.data.findOne();
var localNow = new Date( record.date.getTime() -  ( record.offset * 60000 ) );
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/) for further details

Comment: It works with assumption that application server's (mongo client's) timezone is +5, which may not the case. Original timezone is not persisted anywhere and will be lost unless explicitly saved to a separate property of the document.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @AlexBlex. I have updated my answer. Of course, the recommended way is store the time offset in a field,  however, the Rouse doesn't seem to be allowed to do that.

Comment: @Jaco: this operation returns -1 which this offsets of my mongo server. I could received data from various timezones and I need to keep this information.

Comment: If you really need to keep the time zone information (rather than UTC dates across the board), you will have to save it. I have updated my answer