# Converting String into ISODate in MongoDB using java

Tags: java, date, mongodb-query, isodate

Recently, I have imported CSV file to MongoDB with the date field.
The issue is with the date field, I try to change the date field from string to ISO format.
currently, it show "2016-07-31T04:18:17.000Z". I don't know how to change this into ISO format using java.
I tried this method

```
        String date1 = dr1.getString("created_at");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"); 

        Date Created_at =  df.parse(date1);
        dr1.append("created_at", Created_at);
        Brand_Mention(dr1,collection1,new ObjectId(dr1.get("_id").toString()));
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this!!!

Comment: "2016-07-31T04:18:17.000Z" *is* ISO format... (or an ISO-8601 format, anyway). The second part of your question should be split into a separate question, as it's entirely separate from the formatting side.

Comment: @JonSkeet But I failed to query in mongodb in this format

Comment: That doesn't make the question any clearer... and you still haven't removed the "split the timings" part, which really shouldn't be there.

Comment: It would help if you'd give an example of the *exact* ISO format you're trying to format to.

Comment: kindly review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb

Comment: @JonSkeet ISODate("2016-10-09T11:32:01Z") the format used in MongoDB. While I am trying to perform Aggregation pipeline it works in this (ISODate("2016-10-09T11:32:01Z") format but fails to work for "2016-07-31T04:18:17.000Z"

Comment: Well of that, only the 2016-10-09T11:32:01Z part is the ISO format. The rest is Mongo-specific. But it sounds like you just need to drop the milliseconds and add the `ISODate("...")` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `java.time.Instant` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)) class.

It has method `parse()` to parse your string.
And then you can use `LocalTime.from()` to convert instant time point to local time (that is hours and minutes and seconds without date or timezone).

Then you can compare local times to find needed time range.

Comment: I have tried this method""

Comment: String date1 = dr1.getString("created_at");
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"); 
   
   Date Created_at =  df.parse(date1);
   dr1.append("created_at", Created_at);
   Brand_Mention(dr1,collection1,new ObjectId(dr1.get("_id").toString()));

Comment: But as you see your string "2016-07-31T04:18:17.000Z" is in ISO format, not in "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy". So no need in SimpleDateFormat, use just Instant.parse(dr1.getString("created_at")).

Comment: Also I should note that in Java coding conventions variables and methods are named with small first letter and in camel case. "createdAt", not "Created_at", also "brandMention" instead of "Brand_Mention".

Comment: Thank you!!! I solved this using Javascript.