# Fetch String Date between two Dates in MONGODB?

Tags: mongodb, date

My collections having DATE key ,that is in String format,
so how to query for finding giving date count or i can find how many data is there: 
    I tried one experiment but it is not working ;

```
db.colName.find({"date": {$gte: "Tue Aug 30 16:43:22 IST 2016",$lt: "Tue Aug 30 16:43:22 IST 2016"}})
```

Please suggest is it possible in MongoDB or how how can i find my desire result?

Comment: For best results, convert the string representation of the date to a proper Date type as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all data, parse all dates in the right format and then filter it.

If you are using javascript result save in some variable and do this...

```
result.map(function(singleResult) {
  Date.parse(singleResult.date)
  return singleResult
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with ISODate

```
db.colName.find({"date": {$gte: ISODate("2016-08-30 16:43:22"),$lt: ISODate("2016-08-30 16:43:22")}})
```

Same can be done with javascript Date also

```
db.colName.find({"date": {$gte: new Date("2016-08-30 16:43:22"),$lt: new Date("2016-08-30 16:43:22")}})
```

Comment: He can not, since obviously his dates are saved as strings.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought dates are stored in date format. then there is no way to do it with query, maybe you need to run a script to change the string into date format for all the documents.