# Can I get year and month from below formate using aggregate in Mongoldb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

date was save in below format using moment.

```
 let date= moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

When i try to get the year by using below code. I am getting Undefined as output

```
db.checkouts.aggregate(
    {"$project":{  date:1,
              "year":{"$year":"$date"},
       total:1,
       delivered:1,
       count:1,
       clientName:1,
       clientId:1,
       dealerId:1
    }},{"$match":{
       dealerId:status.UserNumber
    }},function(err,o){
        console.log(o);
        if(o) callback(o);
    }

)
```

Can I get the year from this date format?

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$year` and `$month` are valid with date types only.

Change your type to date to use the above expressions.

Or

You can use `$substr` to extract Year and Month for string date value.

```
$project: {year:{$substr:["$date", 8, 4]}, month:{$substr:["$date", 0, 4]}
```