# How to format date in mongo db 3.2.0

Tags: mongodb

query:

```
    mongo_date_formatter = {
        "$addFields": {
            "Date": {
                "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": "$Date",
                    "format": "%d-%m-%Y"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

date format in database:

```
"Date": "2018-04-15"
```

error i am getting:

```
    OperationFailure at /api/data/
    unknown operator: $dateFromString
```

version on local system:

```
    MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
```

version in server:

```
    3.2.0
```

i tried with:

```
    mongo_date_formatter = {
        "$addFields": {
            "Date": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "date": "$Date",
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This . it is not working.

I thing it is the problem with the server . is there any way to fix it?

Please have a look.

Comment: Could you please share your complete query along with your DB schema and desired result as "$dateToString" used with aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) 
they specify that $dateFromString operator was added at version 3.6.

Comment: @soubhagyapradhan, I'm confused what the edit is?, this operator is unavailable for mongo version 3.2.

Comment: I am using 3.2.0 in mongo db. I with added the query below what i am trying now.

Comment: mongo_date_formatter = {
        "$addFields": {
            "Date": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "date": "$Date",
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: This much i have added

Comment: @soubhagyapradhan you are still using "$dateToString", this is not available in your mongo version.

Comment: Could you please tell me how cann i format the date in 3.2.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Try this query as below :

MongoDB server version: 3.6

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "properDate": {                  // Converting string to Proper date format
                $dateFromString: { 
                    dateString: '$Date',
                } 
            },

        } 
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "FormatedDate": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$properDate" } },
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Bro. I am using 3.2.0 version

Comment: Still searching for a solution. Please wait.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807798/pymongo-date-formatting-issue-while-fetching-data-between-two-dates

Comment: PLease have a look. i have added the question again.

Comment: Using MongoDB versions >= 2.6 and < 3.2
MongoDB does not have the native operators that do the conversion, you would need to manually iterate the cursor returned by the find() method by either using the forEach() method or the cursor method next() to access the documents. Withing the loop, convert the field to an ISODate object and then update the field using the $set operator, as in your case  the field Date currently holds the date in string format.

Comment: Read that post and try to follow the same steps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb